# What will I need if I remove a broken garbage disposal from my kitchen sink?

Tags: plumbing, repair

I have a dual sink tub, with a broken garbage disposal attached to one drain. I just want to take the disposal off, and hook the dishwasher to the sink drain. Will I need to buy any extra tubing and such before i start?

Comment: A picture of the current setup would be very helpful.

Answer (score 8):

Depending on your current setup, you may need a new basket.

[image]

You may also need a new tailpiece with a dishwasher hookup, to bridge the gap between the bottom of the sink and the existing plumbing.

[image]

The old basket can be removed by, removing the locknut then lifting the basket out of the sink. This might require some extra effort, since the old basket will be held in place by plumbers putty.

[image]

Once the old basket is removed, scrape any left over plumbers putty from the sink. Place a new bead of plumbers putty on the lip of the drain hole, and seat the new basket in the bed of putty.

[image]

Slide the rubber gasket, cardboard friction ring, and locknut onto the new basket, then tighten down the locknut. Wipe up any excess putty that squeezed out from under the basket lip.

Reconnect the plumbing, and your done.

For more information on replacing a sink basket, [The Family Handyman](http://www.familyhandyman.com) has a great article on [How to Replace a Kitchen Sink Basket Strainer](http://www.familyhandyman.com/DIY-Projects/Home-Repair/Sink-Repair/how-to-replace-a-kitchen-sink-basket-strainer/Step-By-Step).

Comment: Hmmm. I have a similar sink with a disposal that I rarely use (they're really not good things for the sewage system, either septic tank or municipal), and I've been tempted more than once to retire it but been worried about the complexity of the task. That really doesn't look bad... Tnx!